# Angular 2: importing an export from settings.js into a component file

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular 2 app, I have a `settings.js` file with various exports that I want to use throughout the application:

```
exports.httpPort = 9000;
exports.httpsPort = 1435;
exports.segmentID = 1;
```

I want to export some of these into my ts component file `query.component.ts`, but I'm at a loss on what the correct syntax to do so is.

I see that many .js files have something along the lines of

```
var settings = require('../../settings');
```

which grabs the settings file and then

```
settings.dbConfig
```

Which calls the export, but it doesn't work on my component file.

This is my project file structure:

component.ts
- `project/web/src/app/component.ts`
-Place where I want to import an export from settings.js.

settings.js - `project/server/settings.js`
-File where I want to make the export.

Comment: If you are using the Angular CLI, you may want to use the provided environment files instead of your own settings file.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not my choice, this is how the older developers started the project and I basically have to use how it is right now

Comment: can you try importing with the file type? var settings = require('../../settings.js');

Comment: @LLai That didn't work, but it also didn't recieve an error in my file, but there is an error on my console when I try to compile, reason being that it can't locate settings, I've updated my post with my file structure

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to set the allowJs flag in your tsconfig.json file to allow js module imports.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

Then you can import your settings.js module in your component

```
// component.ts
import * as Settings from '../../../server/settings.js';
```

Now you can use Settings in your component `Settings.httpPort`

Comment: this didn't work for me either, it says "cannot find module", to clarify my settings.js file is purely export statements.  Not sure if that qualifies as a module.

Comment: @Snorlax so it does not include something like module.exports = exports at the end of the settings.js file?

Comment: Correct, although I added it to see if it would change anything and I still have the same error.

Comment: @Snorlax Is '../../../server/settings.js'; the correct path? Just realized I am missing a quote on my answer

Comment: That's what I'm thinking the issue could be, because the path has an error red squiggly line underneath it in my code.  Also, is it correct to have .js at the end of settings in my import statement?  I noticed my other import statements don't have a .js at the end

Comment: @Snorlax yeah it sounds like a path issue. You are correct you do not need the .js on the end of the import. It seems to be fine without it. I was thinking if you don't specify the file type the compiler would think it was a typescript import. But since ts compiles down to js, so it makes sense that it is fine to not include it

Comment: If that's the case, I think I've exhausted all my "./.." patterns., still returns an error

Comment: @Snorlax could you possibly post a snapshot of your file structure? or is moving the settings.js file an option?